# What's the low back support part of a chair called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is that hooked part of an office chair called, which is used to support the lower back?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the lumbar support, the lumbar being the part of the lower back supported.

[image]